# boost::filesystem::exists throws operation not permitted exception on CentOS 8 docker with boost v1.75

Tags: c++, boost, centos8

I use boost 1.75, and on a particular CentOS-8 docker container runs on Ubuntu-18 I get an exception with boost::filesystem::exists() even with a valid path. But if I use the same docker runs on local Mac or Ubuntu-18 there's no issue.

Here is the exception: *C++ exception with description "boost::filesystem::status: Operation not permitted: "../path/*

```
filesystem::path path = filesystem::current_path();
boost::filesystem::exists(path); // throws the same exception
file_status s = boost::filesystem::status(path); // throws the same exception
```

I'm not sure something missed with building the boost static libraries. For the same OS the boost 1.64 has no issue with the above code.

OS : CentOS-8

Compiler : gcc 8.3.1

boost : 1.75, compiled on local CentOS-8 docker with gcc-8.3.1.

Comment: Not sure if it is related but when I had problems with Boost filesystem, the reason was an ABI change between different gcc versions (Boost was compiled with a really old gcc and I was trying to compile my program with a relatively new gcc). So make sure Boost is compiled with a compatible ABI.

Comment: @PaulG. Sorry missed to mention that the boost is compiled on CentOS-8 using gcc-8.3.1. Updated the description with more details.

Comment: Looks like something was truncated here: _`"boost::filesystem::status: Operation not permitted: "../path/`_. Can you post the entire message, preferrable as a code block, so it's fully intact? In particular the `../` gives me the idea that you're looking at a genuine permissions issue due to security restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem at work. Running `docker run --privileged` "solved" the issue. We ended up replacing `boost::filesystem::exists()` with `std::filesystem::exists()` which solved the issue without the `--privileged` flag (gcc10 though).